# Redis docker with notification enabled

Tags: docker, redis

I can't run redis in docker with `notify-keyspace-events KEA` enabled.
Redis is running but my client doesn't receive the keyspace-events. The redis.conf file is used (as I can see) and it is copied in the container.
I tried the following command:

```
docker run --rm -v ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -p 6379:6379 --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

I also tried build a new image with the copied redis.conf with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM redis
EXPOSE 6379
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
RUN chmod 666 /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

This one I tried with and without the chmod (I'm building the image on windows).

If I start a redis instance local on the host all is working so the redis.conf can't be wrong.

Comment: Did you exec or otherwise read the conf file in the container to make sure it's there? Try using an absolute path to define the volume (file) mount for the conf file.

Comment: Yes I made a cat /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf | more to check

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to modify line 1923 of the Redis.conf file to have: `notify-keyspace-events "KEA"`

The default config does not enable Keyspace notification, but this line will enable them